# How to merge first 12 columns?

Tags: python, bash, text, awk, sed

I have a text file which contains text like:

```
Somename of someone                                   1234 7894
Even some more name                                   2345 5343
Even more of the same                                 6572 6456
I am a customer                                       1324 7894
I am another customer                                 5612 3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three            9631 7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list   8529 9369
And here I am                                         4567 9876
```

I need to make a CSV file from this, but the problem is that the name contains 12 columns, so I need to merge all from the first 12 columns to 1 column so the CSV file will look like:

```
Somename of someone,123456,789456
```

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-11  test | sed "s/[[:space:]]/\\ /g" | sed "s/\t/\\ /g" > test1
```

gives me a file with the first 12 columns.

Comment: Any chance the last two columns are tab separated and the subparts of the names are space separated? If that's the case it would be easy to achieve this using pandas (since you've tagged Python here)

Comment: post a more representable record (containing 12 words in its 1st column) and post the final expected result

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\)$/,\1,\2/' file > newfile` will do what you need.

Comment: @Dan I don't know panda's very well,...

Comment: Try this maybe: `import pandas as pd`, `df = pd.read_csv('mydata.txt', sep='\t')`, `df.to_csv('mydata_output.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: 
/code
I am a customer                                                        1324 7894
I am another customer                                              5612 3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three          9631 7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list   8529 9369
And here I am                                                            4567 9876
/code

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed for \s/\S shorthand for space/non-space and -E to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/,\1,\2/' file
Somename of someone,1234,7894
Even some more name,2345,5343
Even more of the same,6572,6456
I am a customer,1324,7894
I am another customer,5612,3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three,9631,7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list,8529,9369
And here I am,4567,9876
```

and the functional equivalent with any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)$/,\1,\2/' file
Somename of someone,1234,7894
Even some more name,2345,5343
Even more of the same,6572,6456
I am a customer,1324,7894
I am another customer,5612,3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three,9631,7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list,8529,9369
And here I am,4567,9876
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{x=$(NF-1) OFS $NF; sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){2}$/,""); print $0, x}' file
Somename of someone,1234,7894
Even some more name,2345,5343
Even more of the same,6572,6456
I am a customer,1324,7894
I am another customer,5612,3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three,9631,7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list,8529,9369
And here I am,4567,9876
```

Comment: I take this to be more robust if you don't trust the input data to always be of fixed width?

Comment: Yes and I generally consider sed first when the requirement is simple substitutions on individual lines anyway as the code for that is usually concise and efficient, especially with GNU sed. To be honest if I were going to use awk for this I wouldn't treat it as fixed width fields anyway. I'll add an awk solution just as an FYI. One sec....

Comment: I see. But not having to read all the regular expressions is an advantage of FIELDWIDTHS don't you think?

Comment: Could be but the code I posted won't have a performance issue that changing to FIELDWIDTHS would help with and IMHO it's not worth the non-portability, reduced robustness, and added complexity in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If the different columns related to the name are part of the same CSV column, and should therefore be left untouched, why not working on the last two columns only?

```sh
$ sed 's/\t* *\([0-9]\+\)\t* *\([0-9]\+\)$/,\1,\2/' input_file
Somename of someone,123456,789456
Even some more name,234567,534312
Even more of the same,657212,645613
```

Comment: It corresponds to the expected output you wrote in your question, doesn't it? What is missing? The double quotes around the first part of the name? If so it should not be difficult to add: `sed 's/\(.*[a-z]\)[ \t]\+\([0-9]\+\)[ \t]\+\([0-9]\+\)$/"\1",\2,\3/'`

Comment: @EdMorton My scripot is fine, thanks :). My point is “don't try to merge the first 12 columns, work on the last 2 instead”. I am not trying to provide the single best portable solution ever, especially because anyone who tries to reuse that for a similar case will likely have to adapt it anyway. I do like your version with the `\s` and `\S` though, it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using GNU AWK instead, you can do this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "54 5 5"; OFS = ","} {print $1, $2, $3}' FILE
```

Further explanation:

- You really have 3 columns of fixed width data thus `FIELDWIDTHS = "54 5 5"`
- You want the output field separator to be a comma thus `OFS = ","`

Note that FIELDWIDTHS is a feature of GNU AWK.

If you don't mind the whitespace being preserved in our CSV, then you're done.

Or, if you also need the white space removed, then:

```awk
# test.gawk

BEGIN {
  FIELDWIDTHS = "54 5 5"
  OFS = ","
}
{
  for (f=1; f<=NF; f++) {
    sub(/ +$/, "", $f)   # Delete whitespace.
  }
  print
}
```

Testing:

```
▶ gawk -f test.gawk FILE
Somename of someone,1234,7894
Even some more name,2345,5343
Even more of the same,6572,6456
I am a customer,1324,7894
I am another customer,5612,3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three,9631,7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list,8529,9369
And here I am,4567,9876
```

(Note that in the second version, as suggested by Ed Morton in comments, I was able to just use `print` at the end, because we modified the fields which effectively updates `$0` and the field separators are replaced by `OFS`.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain are the first columns a name and how many name columns are their maximum, ahead of the numerals?
Knowing that can make it relatively easy to add commas and save to a .csv.

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' ','
```

Comment: Problem is, the input is a formatted view of mainframe, if I do for example awk {'print $5'} I get sometimes the last column, some lines a part of the second column, and mainly a part of the first column,...

Comment: if I run cut -d ' ' -f1-11  inputfile | sed "s/[[:space:]]/\\ /g" | sed "s/\t/\\ /g" | awk '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5":"$6":"$7":"$8":"$9":"$10":"$11":"$12}' > output
I get a file with only the name separated with a : in one column. Then the next part,... how to get the numbers in it,...

Comment: `tr` would replace all blanks across the whole line with commas, including the ones within the first field of words.

Answer (score 0):

a *hacky* `awk`

```
$ awk '{last="," $(NF-1) "," $NF; NF-=2; print $0 last}' file 

Somename of someone,1234,7894
Even some more name,2345,5343
Even more of the same,6572,6456
I am a customer,1324,7894
I am another customer,5612,3657
Also I am a customer and I am number Three,9631,7411
And I am number four and not the latest one in list,8529,9369
And here I am,4567,9876
```

capture the last two columns, reduce column count which will also normalize spacing; then print.